# Type cast from Method to SEL

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, selector, objective-c-runtime

I’m using the Objective-C runtime library, function class_copyMethodList(), to get a list of all the methods in my class. How do I then convert those type Method objects into usable type SEL objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run the function `method_getName()` on the returned Method objects.

Answer (score 3):

I did this a couple of years back to extract all the names of a class's methods.  You could use NSSelectorFromString() to get the SEL from each name.

```
+ (NSArray *) methodNamesForClass:(Class) aClass
{
    Method *methods;
    unsigned int methodCount;
    if (methods = class_copyMethodList(aClass, &methodCount))
    {
        NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:methodCount];
        while (methodCount--) 
            [results addObject:[NSString stringWithCString: sel_getName(method_getName(methods[methodCount])) 
                                                  encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        free(methods);  
        return results;
    }

    return nil;
}
```

Comment: You already have the SEL at the `sel_getName()` stage. Seems a bit silly to convert it to a string and back.

Comment: When I wrote this, what I needed was the names.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you have the name of the method, you can convert it to a selector using the `NSSelectorFromString` function.

```
SEL fooSelector = NSSelectorFromString ( @"foo:" ) ;
```

Apple discusses this in their [Objective C tutorial](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html).

Comment: He has a list of Method values, not NSStrings naming selectors.

Comment: yeah but I could use the method_getName() method to nest and get a selector out of it